# ERROR: null value in column "album_id" of relation "songs" violates not-null constraint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, postman, spring-boot-maven-plugin

## The entity classes are as given below

I am not sure if this is problem with how Hibernate or Spring Data understands my input. In my project on backend I am using Java + Spring Data + Hibernate + PostgreSQL.
I am able to get and delete data from the database but not add to it.

```
//AlbumEntity


``
@Entity
@Table(name = "albums")
public class AlbumEntity extends ApplicationPersistenceEntity implements Album {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "album_id")
  // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long albumId;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String albumName;

  @Column(name = "Genre")
  private String genre;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "singer_id", nullable = false)
  // @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  private SingerEntity singer;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "album")
  private List<SongEntity> songs;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
   * The constructor.
   */
  public AlbumEntity() {

  }

  /**
   * The constructor.
   *
   * @param albumId
   * @param albumName
   * @param genre
   * @param singer
   * @param songs
   */
  public AlbumEntity(long albumId, String albumName, String genre, SingerEntity singer, List<SongEntity> songs) {

    super();
    this.albumId = albumId;
    this.albumName = albumName;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.singer = singer;
    this.songs = songs;
  }

  /**
   * @return albumId
   */
  @Override
  public long getAlbumId() {

    return this.albumId;
  }

  /**
   * @param albumId new value of {@link #getalbumId}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setAlbumId(long albumId) {

    this.albumId = albumId;
  }

  /**
   * @return albumName
   */
  @Override
  public String getAlbumName() {

    return this.albumName;
  }

  /**
   * @param albumName new value of {@link #getalbumName}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setAlbumName(String albumName) {

    this.albumName = albumName;
  }

  /**
   * @return genre
   */
  @Override
  public String getGenre() {

    return this.genre;
  }

  /**
   * @param genre new value of {@link #getgenre}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setGenre(String genre) {

    this.genre = genre;
  }

  /**
   * @return singer
   */
  public SingerEntity getSinger() {

    return this.singer;
  }

  /**
   * @param singer new value of {@link #getsinger}.
   */
  public void setSinger(SingerEntity singer) {

    this.singer = singer;
  }

  /**
   * @return songs
   */
  public List<SongEntity> getSongs() {

    return this.songs;
  }

  /**
   * @param songs new value of {@link #getsongs}.
   */
  public void setSongs(List<SongEntity> songs) {

    this.songs = songs;
  }

  @Override
  @Transient
  public Long getSingerId() {

    if (this.singer == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.singer.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public void setSingerId(Long singerId) {

    if (singerId == null) {
      this.singer = null;
    } else {
    SingerEntity singerEntity = new SingerEntity();
      singerEntity.setId(singerId);
      this.singer = singerEntity;
    }
  }

}
```

```
//Song Entity


@Entity
@Table(name = "songs")
public class SongEntity extends ApplicationPersistenceEntity implements Song {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "song_id")
  // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long songId;

  @Column(name = "Title")
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "Content")
  private String content;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "singer_id", nullable = false)
  private SingerEntity singer;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "album_id")
  private AlbumEntity album;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
   * The constructor.
   */
  public SongEntity() {

  }

  /**
   * The constructor.
   *
   * @param songId
   * @param title
   * @param content
   * @param singer
   * @param album
   */
  public SongEntity(long songId, String title, String content, SingerEntity singer, AlbumEntity album) {

    super();
    this.songId = songId;
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
    this.singer = singer;
    this.album = album;
  }

  /**
   * @return songId
   */
  @Override
  public long getSongId() {

    return this.songId;
  }

  /**
   * @param songId new value of {@link #getsongId}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setSongId(long songId) {

    this.songId = songId;
  }

  /**
   * @return title
   */
  @Override
  public String getTitle() {

    return this.title;
  }

  /**
   * @param title new value of {@link #gettitle}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setTitle(String title) {

    this.title = title;
  }

  /**
   * @return content
   */
  @Override
  public String getContent() {

    return this.content;
  }

  /**
   * @param content new value of {@link #getcontent}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setContent(String content) {

    this.content = content;
  }

  /**
   * @return singer
   */
  public SingerEntity getSinger() {

    return this.singer;
  }

  /**
   * @param singer new value of {@link #getsinger}.
   */
  public void setSinger(SingerEntity singer) {

    this.singer = singer;
  }

  /**
   * @return album
   */
  public AlbumEntity getAlbum() {

    return this.album;
  }

  /**
   * @param album new value of {@link #getalbum}.
   */
  public void setAlbum(AlbumEntity album) {

    this.album = album;
  }

  @Override
  @Transient
  public Long getSingerId() {

    if (this.singer == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.singer.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public void setSingerId(Long singerId) {

    if (singerId == null) {
      this.singer = null;
    } else {
      SingerEntity singerEntity = new SingerEntity();
      singerEntity.setId(singerId);
      this.singer = singerEntity;
    }
  }

  @Override
  @Transient
  public Long getAlbumId() {

    if (this.album == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.album.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public void setAlbumId(Long albumId) {

    if (albumId == null) {
      this.album = null;
    } else {
      AlbumEntity albumEntity = new AlbumEntity();
      albumEntity.setId(albumId);
      this.album = albumEntity;
    }
  }

}
```

```
singer entity


@Entity
@Table(name = "singers")
public class SingerEntity extends ApplicationPersistenceEntity implements Singer {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "singer_id")
  // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long singerId;

  @Column(name = "First_NAME")
  private String firstname;

  @Column(name = "Last_NAME")
  private String lastname;

  @Column(name = "Gender")
  private String gender;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "singer")
  private List<SongEntity> songs;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "singer")
  private List<AlbumEntity> albums;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
   * The constructor.
   */
  public SingerEntity() {

  }

  /**
   * The constructor.
   *
   * @param singerId
   * @param firstname
   * @param lastname
   * @param gender
   * @param songs
   * @param albums
   */
  public SingerEntity(long singerId, String firstname, String lastname, String gender, List<SongEntity> songs,
      List<AlbumEntity> albums) {

    super();
    this.singerId = singerId;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.songs = songs;
    this.albums = albums;
  }

  /**
   * @return singerId
   */
  @Override
  public long getSingerId() {

    return this.singerId;
  }

  /**
   * @param singerId new value of {@link #getsingerId}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setSingerId(long singerId) {

    this.singerId = singerId;
  }

  /**
   * @return firstname
   */
  @Override
  public String getFirstname() {

    return this.firstname;
  }

  /**
   * @param firstname new value of {@link #getfirstname}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setFirstname(String firstname) {

    this.firstname = firstname;
  }

  /**
   * @return lastname
   */
  @Override
  public String getLastname() {

    return this.lastname;
  }

  /**
   * @param lastname new value of {@link #getlastname}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setLastname(String lastname) {

    this.lastname = lastname;
  }

  /**
   * @return gender
   */
  @Override
  public String getGender() {

    return this.gender;
  }

  /**
   * @param gender new value of {@link #getgender}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setGender(String gender) {

    this.gender = gender;
  }

  /**
   * @return songs
   */
  public List<SongEntity> getSongs() {

    return this.songs;
  }

  /**
   * @param songs new value of {@link #getsongs}.
   */
  public void setSongs(List<SongEntity> songs) {

    this.songs = songs;
  }

  /**
   * @return albums
   */
  public List<AlbumEntity> getAlbums() {

    return this.albums;
  }

  /**
   * @param albums new value of {@link #getalbums}.
   */
  public void setAlbums(List<AlbumEntity> albums) {

    this.albums = albums;
  }

}
```

While checking Post endpoint

```
    "modificationCounter": 2,
    "id": 302,
    "songId": 302,
    "title": "As it was",
    "content": "songs",
    "singer_id": 201,
    "album_id": 101
```

I am giving this data...still there is this error

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "album_id" of relation "songs" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (302, 2, 302, As it was, songs, null, null).
```

Answer (score 0):

This one keeps on coming... I guess you are using your entities as DTOs. **DON'T**

The problem is that you send an ID for albumID and singerID which are objects in Java.

For this to work, create a DTO that maps your fields and lookup the IDs in your database then create your Song Entity with those. Also, you need to map back the song in your album and singer for JPA to work correctly.